# Problema al implementar botón en software de notas con Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Estoy trabajando un proyecto con Laravel donde se administran notas de estudiantes. Tengo un archivo `students.blade.php` en donde se reflejan las notas de la siguiente manera:

```
@foreach ($indicators as $indicator)
 <td class="center">
{{ number_format($notes[ $indicator->id ] ?? 0, 2) }}
 </td>
@endforeach
```

Y tengo una funcionalidad que me permite cambiar la nota manualmente mediante un input así:

```
<a href="{{ route('web.notes.students-indicators', [$entity->id, $student->id]) }}" data-title="Notas Estudiante: {{ $student->full_name }}" data-reload="1" class="swal-ajax green-text tooltipped" data-position="top" data-tooltip="Notas Estudiante: {{ $student->full_name }}"  ><i class="fa fa-book-reader"></i></a>
```

Este código está conectado a un archivo que se llama `fields.blade.php` y permite modificar la nota mediante el input así:

```
<input type="hidden" name="notes[{{ $loop->index }}][indicator_id]" value="{{ $indicator->id }}">
<input type="number" class="input_note" name="notes[{{ $loop->index }}][note]" step="0.01" value="{{ $notes[ $indicator->id ] ?? 0 }}" min="0" max="100">
```

Lo que quisiera saber es cómo podría cambiar una nota a un estudiante mediante un botón pasando una nota default, por ejemplo: 3.5 y asignarle esa nota en vez de hacerlo manual con el input, agradezco me puedan dar camino a una solución.